# How do I set the default terminal profile?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, default

So I was messing around with profiles in the Terminal, I was wondering how to make the profile I setup as the default profile whenever I load up terminal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Under **Edit → Profiles** set the "Profile used when opening a new terminal" to the profile you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't see that when I was looking around

Comment: Edit -> Preferences -> Profile

Answer (score 1):

In Ubutnu 22.04 :

1. Open Terminal
2. Click on hamburger menu and select preferences
   [image]
3. Click on arrow next to the profile you want to set as default and click "Set as default"
   [image]